# Why can tortoisesvn update,commit,but can not show log?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

1. TortoiseSVN can update, commit, but can not show log. After I changed an svn client to SmartSVN, it can show log. I can also use svn show log in the Linux command line.
2. The error message is as follows:

   `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

[image: https://preview.ibb.co/kXozxk/svnerror.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use fiddler to capture SmartSVN and TortoiseSVN package. I found something  strange. Sorry,I can not show the image directly.
[fiddler capture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in7XV.png)

As you can see, 1-8 are TortiseSVN packages. 9-15 are SmartSVN packages. I compared 2-5 packages and 10-14 packages. The differences between two these packages are only directory and user agent and date.

TortoiseSVM requests got an error in [the 8th package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY8iX.png)(Error message:Could not open the requested SVN file system). SmartSVN last two request just (14-15 package) works fine.

I googled this error message and someone suggests changing TortoiseSVN version to a lower or higher version.

So I changed my TortoiseSVN version from 1.9.5 to 1.9.1. And it works.Hope this answer can save someone's time.

But I still want to know the reason behind this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom pane of the Log dialog also has a context menu that allows you to 
Show log

```
Show the revision log for the selected single file.
```

Comment: TortoiseSVN cache has nothing to do with this error.

Comment: TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Network " which provides a means to configure a proxy server.  It was a proxy issue. I entered in the right proxy information and voila! I was granted access.

Comment: Also , According to the error message, you may have a check that whether the svnserver is listening at IPV6 or not.

Comment: I cleared cahe and checked TortoiseSVN settings.I did not open any proxy.Still, it can update,commit,but can not show log(A single file or a directory).I don't think it's an access issue.Because I can use show log  in the Linux command line.